# How to add and play .mov file in unity project

Tags: video, unity-game-engine, .mov

I'm trying to add .mov file into my unity project and want to play that video file in a scene.how can i create a scene with video playing in unity 3d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks,It was the problem with Unity Pro version.Now i'm working with Unity Pro and Videos are working properly .

U can use the following  javascript after importing the video file into asset folder .

```
var movTexture : MovieTexture;    //create a MovieTexture variable

function Start () 
{      
   renderer.material.mainTexture = movTexture;
   movTexture.Play();
}

function Update () 
{
   if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) {
        if (movTexture.isPlaying) {
            movTexture.Pause();
        }
        else {
            movTexture.Play();
        }
    }
    
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        movTexture.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to install QuickTime if you are using Windows for development. Otherwise, you will not be able to import *.mov file into your project.  Here is small instruction how to import and play video in Unity3d: http://druss.co/2015/05/unity3d-how-to-play-video-in-unity-project-movietexture/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you can do, if you have Unity Pro, is use [Movie Textures](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/VideoFiles.html).

> Movie Textures are animated Textures that are created from a video
>   file. By placing a video file in your project's Assets Folder, you can
>   import the video to be used exactly as you would use a regular
>   Texture.

If you do NOT have Unity Pro, then you are out of luck unless you want to try using one of the methods outlined in [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/16296/movie-playback-any-way-to-get-around-not-having-un.html) answer, however I would not recommend that because of poor performance.